# scala read large files

Tags: scala, large-files, bytearrayoutputstream

Hello I am looking for fastest bat rather hi-level way to work with large data collection. 
My task consist of two task read alot of large files in memory and then make some statistical calculations (the easiest way to work with data in this task is random access array ).

My first approach was to use `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`, becuase it can resize it's internal storage .

```
def packTo(buf:java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream,f:File) = {
  try {
    val fs = new java.io.FileInputStream(f)
    IOUtils.copy(fs,buf)
  } catch  {
    case e:java.io.FileNotFoundException =>
  }
}

    val buf = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream()
    files foreach { f:File  => packTo(buf,f) } 
    println(buf.size())

    for(i <- 0 to buf.size()) {
       for(j <- 0 to buf.size()) {
          for(k <- 0 to buf.size()) {
       //  println("i  " + i + "  " + buf[i] );
                   // Calculate something amathing using buf[i] buf[j] buf[k] 
          }
       }
    }

    println("amazing = " + ???)
```

but `ByteArrayOutputStream` can't get me as `byte[]` only copy of it. But I can not allow to have 2 copies of data .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried [scala-io](http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.2/index.html#!/core/basic_input)? Should be as simple as `Resource.fromFile(f).byteArray` with it.

Comment: thnx for your answer.  scala-io looks as very reasonable solution , but how can I efficient concat Arrays[]  . here may be is approach http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.2/index.html#!/core/add_all_bytes - I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Scala's built in library already provides a nice API to do this

```
io.Source.fromFile("/file/path").mkString.getBytes
```

However, it's not often a good idea to load whole file as byte array into memory. Do make sure the largest possible file can still fit into your JVM memory properly.

Comment: If file is really large as OP says, this one will yield [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory)

Comment: If the file does not contain text, conversion to a `String` is meaningless and perilous. In any event, conversion to a `String` in order to get the file's original bytes is both too expensive and not guaranteed to yield the original bytes. Lastly, it's inadvisable to perform byte-sequence -> `String` or `String` -> byte sequence transformations without specifying an encoding.

Comment: We do need to specify encoding, it's just implicit. The full method signature is `def fromFile(name : String)(implicit codec : Codec)`. Yes there are performance overhead to convert from `File` -> `String` -> `Array[Byte]` but most of the time (especially when writing some scripts) it's not worth spending even more expensive developer time to explore and resolve external libraries